# Ubuntu update failing on my brand new BQ aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My phone came preinstalled with 14.10 and I'm trying to update it to the latest version and it's downloading up to 99%.

Then, after a while, I'm getting `installation failed`. I tried twice but both updates failed.

*Please advise me how to complete this update.*

Comment: I accept Ubuntu! 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)  r21 reached EOL. Please share the procedure to upgrade to ubuntu latest version

Comment: This is about a phone. 14.10 (r21) is the version shipped with new Ubuntu phones, when they are bought new. I don't think it is a good idea to tell those people that their version is not supported....

Comment: When you buy a phone, it's on 14.10, so IMHO a ton of people are going to get this , so it should remain open....

Answer (score 1):

Contact the support department from BQ themselves [here](http://www.bq.com/gb/support/aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition) as you need specialised tools to flash your phone from a computer (this can be a Windows computer, no Ubuntu computer necessary).

BQ will help you for free if your phone is still under warranty.  If your phone is out of warranty, come back here and leave a comment below this post.